# How to ignore an invalid SSL certificate with requests_html?

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, web-scraping, python-requests

So basically I'm trying to scrap the javascript generated data from a website. To do this, I'm using the Python library [requests_html](http://html.python-requests.org).

Here is my code :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://myurl'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {'mylog': 'root', 'mypass': 'root'}

r = session.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False, data=payload)
r.html.render()
load = r.html.find('#load_span', first=True)

print (load.text)
```

If I don't use the render() function, I can connect to the website and my scraped data is null (which is normal) but when I use it, I have this error :

```
pyppeteer.errors.PageError: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID at https://myurl
```

or

```
net::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM
```

I assume the parameter "verify=False" of session.post is ignored by the render. How do I do it ?

Edit : If you want to reproduce the error :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests

session = HTMLSession()

url = 'https://wrong.host.badssl.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = session.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

r.html.render()

load = r.html.find('#content', first=True)

print (load)
```

Comment: Wich version of python and request lib are you using?

Comment: @Alessandro I'm using python3.6 and requests_html 0.9.0

Comment: Wich OS are you using? It's quite difficult to reproduce this error in the same way that you do.

Comment: @Alessandro I'm under MacOS, I think it's possible to reproduce with any site with no verified certificate.

Comment: @Alessandro I edited the post to provide a reproduction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way is to set the `ignoreHTTPSErrors` parameter in [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer). The problem is that requests_html doesn't provide any way to set this parameter, in fact, there is an [issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/issues/174) about it. My advice is to ping again the developers by adding another message here.

Or maybe you can pull this new feature.

Another way is to use Selenium.

**EDIT:**
I added `verify=False` as a feature with a pull request (accepted). Now is possible to ignore the SSL error :)

It's not a parameter of the Get() [set it when you instantiate the object](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/174#issuecomment-464950428):

```
session = HTMLSession(verify=False)
```

Comment: I will try Selenium. I updated the issue on the html_request GitHub. Thanks for the advices

Comment: I see. I'll follow the issue too since I'm really interested in this feature. Don't forget to choose your favorite answer when you think that this issue has been solved.

Comment: I managed to success but it's a bit dirty. Go in file "python3.x/site-packages/pyppeteer/requests_html.py", and in line 680 add the parameter : `self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=True, headless=True, args=['--no-sandbox']))`

Comment: Yeah, this could be part of a pull request.