# Get JavaScript Web by requests-html given OpenSSL.SSL.Error'SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm following this [guide of requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) library and found this error in my laptop.

In JavaScript Support I try to code like this page:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')
r.html.render()
print(r.text)
```

When ran this code I received this content in Sublimetext:

> [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download.
>   Download may take a few minutes.
>   OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

Can anyone fix this problem for me, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore an invalid SSL certificate with requests\_html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762655/how-to-ignore-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-with-requests-html)

Answer (score 3):

I solve problem with :

```
pip install pyppdf
```

then in the code first use:

```
import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
```

Source : https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/258#issuecomment-563075764